# Realm access across threads with rxjava and dagger2

Tags: java, android, multithreading, realm

I've read many posts regarding this topic but it's still a little unclear to me. I understand you can't access `Realm` class or realm objects across different threads so I'm wondering what the optimal way is to handle that.

I have a service that starts a thread. That thread does background work (including work via `rxjava` on `Schedulers.io`). Now at a certain point I want to save some data to realm which lives in a DataManager class. Originally I was using `Dagger2` to inject `Realm` into my DataManager class (which was itself injected into the service). However this won't work since the injection was done on the main thread so `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` is tied to the main thread but it is accessed in DataManager from a different thread.

The only feasiblbe option I can think of is to call `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` and `realm.close()` at the beginning and end of every method that is doing a transaction. I don't mind doing this but I'm wondering if there will be  performance hit calling `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` every time I want to save an object. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` will be a bit slow if it is the first instance among all threads. Otherwise, it returns instantly since Realm is caching the schemas internally. See https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2231

Comment: FYI I decided to abandon Realm for my specific use case. I basically needed to do a `copyFromRealm` on all my fetched objects so I could pass them across threads and then the live object benefit was pretty much out the door. It was also a paint to manage closing realm instances inside of helper classes. I'm sure there's a better way to handle this but decided to stick with sqlite and an orm.

Answer (score 0):

I tackled the threading issue while using Realm in one of my apps by creating a `DatabaseManager` class which I injected into Activities and Services using Dagger 2.

So for example if I have an entity `Task`, the `DatabaseManager` class had a method `void update(Task task)` which would get the default Realm instance, fetch the `Task` with the given ID from Realm database, update the obtained `Task` instance in a Transaction block, execute `realm.copyFromRealm(updatedTask);` and close the Realm instance at the end of method.

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                // fetch the object from Realm database and update it as required.

                //https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#copyFromRealm-E-
                // Makes an unmanaged in-memory copy of an already persisted RealmObject.
                realm.copyFromRealm(task);

                }
            }
        });
realm.close();
```

It worked for me. If there's a better approach I would like to know more.